# Check the values of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on building a tic-tac-toe game where a variety of combinations could potentially produce a winner. I have created an array that holds the winning combinations (I'm using jquery, hence I have stored them as strings that correspond to an ID in my HTML):

```
var winningCombos = [
                ["#0", "#1", "#2"],
                ["#0", "#4", "#8"],
                ["#0", "#3", "#6"],
                ["#1", "#4", "#7"],
                ["#2", "#4", "#6"],
                ["#2", "#5", "#8"],
                ["#3", "#4", "#5"],
                ["#5", "#6", "#7"]
            ]
```

I have written some code that successfully checks whether any of these combinations contain all "x" or all "y", and when they do, a winner is identified. However, what I am trying to do now is to figure out a way to test if 2 out of 3 of any of the combinations contain either "x" or "y". If they do, then the computer should try to "block" the winning combination by filling the remaining square that would give the win.

For example: I want to check each combination and if #0 and #1 both equal "X", then the computer should put a "O" in #2 to block the win.

I'm having a hard time conceptualizing how to do this. I know that others have implemented minimax algorithms for this type of thing, but I'm still a beginner and really don't understand how they work yet.

**More Information**

Someone asked about how I am representing the board and how I am checking for wins currrently.

**The Game Board:**

```
        <div class="row" id="row1">
            <div class="square" id="0"></div>
            <div class="square" id="1"></div>
            <div class="square" id="2"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="row2">
            <div class="square" id="3"></div>
            <div class="square" id="4"></div>
            <div class="square" id="5"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="row3">
            <div class="square" id="6"></div>
            <div class="square" id="7"></div>
            <div class="square" id="8"></div>
        </div>
```

**Checking for Win**

```
    function checkForWin() {
          for (var i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
           //console.log($(winningCombos[i][0]).text().indexOf("X"));
           if ($(winningCombos[i][0]).text().indexOf("X") >= 0 && $(winningCombos[i][1]).text().indexOf("X") >= 0 && $(winningCombos[i][2]).text().indexOf("X") >= 0) {
           gameOver("x")
       } else if ($(winningCombos[i][0]).text().indexOf("O") >= 0 && $(winningCombos[i][1]).text().indexOf("O") >= 0 && $(winningCombos[i][2]).text().indexOf("O") >= 0) {
           gameOver("o");
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: So loop over and check if two of the three are equal. [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: What does your datastructure representing the playingfield look like? Or if you do not have one, how do you currently check for a winner?

Comment: I would actually skip hard-coding the winning combos. Instead, loop through the playing board "grid" horizontally, then vertically, then the diagonals, and just count how many matches in a row there are.

Answer (score 1):

I would create two loops:

1. In first loop over Your array computer checks if user has two of three possible options, if so blocks the third field.
2. Second loop - if first loop ended with no move. In second computer try to win by completing one of not-blocked win possibilities from array ( after chosing row to complete computer should stay on it till it will be blocked or computer win ).

For better performance i would create two extra structures:

- for computer win - structure will remove rows where user took field and win by that row is not possible anymore by the computer
- for user win - structure will remove rows where computer has taken any field and win by that row is not possible anymore by the user

Thanks that extra structures checking both things - blocking user, and finding possible row for win needs less loop count.

My solution is based on Your orginal idea - array of win combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go a bit differently. You can use a bit more structure of the game inside your code. Lest imagine the following structure for the game field, where bold numbers depict the possible winning line number:

> ***0 1 2 3 4***
>    ***5*** 0 1 2
>    ***6*** 3 4 5
>    ***7*** 6 7 8

Now you can produce a map of cell number to winning lines

```
0 - 0,1,5 // meaning that when 0 contains X, it may be a part of winning combos 0,1 and 5
1 - 2,5
2 - 3,4,5
3 - 1,6
4 - 0,2,6
5 - 3,6
6 - 1,4,7
7 - 2,7
8 - 0,3,7
```

Now, Imagine that you have an array of 8 number, one for each line [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] . You have to run a loop over your cells and for each cell that has X in it, you increase a counter for all the lines the combos the cell is mapping into. For example, if cell 1 is checked with X, then array will become: [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]. After you have iterated over all 9 cells, your combo array will contain numbers from 0 to 3. Ofc, if any of those is 3, then game over. You were interested in the first entry that has 2 in it. Ofc, you can do calculations for both X and O while you are iterating the field.

This solution allows you do a 1 pass over the field to calculate the game